# Amazon Cognito - Can you add a custom claim to the access_token when using Client Credentials Flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using Amazon Cognito as an authorization server. I managed to setup everything and get an access_token using Client Credentials but now i need to add a custom claim to the token. is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

After contacting AWS Support, they confirmed that Amazon Cognito doesn't support adding custom claims to the access token using Client Credentials Flow.

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this scenario?

Comment: Cognito is by far the worse AWS product... Last project I saw working around this was setting custom scoped in the client, and then giving access to resources based on the scopes. Dirty and unsafe hack, but that's what AWS forces us to do.